# Use buttons inside subview

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a multiple choice quiz game, and my goal right now is to have four buttons that refresh by spinning around with new answer choices.  I *think* that means I need a subview that animates and re-populates with new buttons--if that's incorrect or not best, please stop me here.

At any rate, I created the subview in my storyboard, put the buttons inside it (background is blue just to see it now):

[image]

I dragged that over to my ViewController to make an IBOutlet (`buttonContainer`) and added this code to my ViewDidLoad:

```
view.addSubview(buttonContainer)
let buttonTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: Selector("checkAnswer"))
buttonTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
buttonContainer.addGestureRecognizer(buttonTap)
buttonContainer.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

However:  When I run it in the simulator, the blue background does not appear at all, but the buttons are still disabled.

Before creating the subview, both the buttons and the function (`checkAnswer`) they called all worked perfectly.

Comment: whether you programatically create Button and View or used storyBoard?

Comment: I used storyBoard to create everything

Comment: and if u used storyboard to create UI there  is no need of adding it to view so remove this line  view.addSubview(buttonContainer)

Comment: Are the buttons UIButtons? Are you adding tap gesture recognizers to buttons?

Comment: They are UIButtons--they worked fine before including them on the subview, but didn't tap once I added them into the subview.  I was trying to add the tap gesture to the subview container.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any of this code if you are creating everything in storyboard. Just create a new class for the containerview and connect the buttons as an outlet collection.

For example, your button container class might look something like this:

```
class ButtonContainerView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var answerButtons: [UIButton]!

    func rotateButtons() {
        for button in answerButtons {
            var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: &context)
            UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.Linear)
            UIView.setAnimationDuration(5.0)
            button.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(button.transform, CGFloat(M_PI))
            UIView.commitAnimations()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the buttons themselves animate?  It was my understanding that I needed to use a view.

Comment: UIButton inherits from UIView. You can animate it with this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:

Comment: I'm new to all this, but it's my understanding that a view would use `view.transitionWithView(...)` but putting that method on my button raises an error--does not have a member named 'transitionWithView'.  Pretty lost and can't find any resources that explain how to animate buttons in this way.

Comment: It is a class method so you would use it like UIView.transitionWithView([insert the animation code here])

Comment: Actually on second thought just use the transform variable. See my example above.

Comment: It seems like this rotates clockwise about the center; I'm looking to flip the button from back to front, with a new text value on it. @Allan Chau